# Download a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, hyperlink

I'm trying to download a CSV file, but my code produces a file containing HTML. If you download with a browser, however, it downloads the file properly.

How can I download the file using java?

This is my code:

```
public void downloadData()
{
    String stringUrl = "http://www.pais.co.il/123/Pages/last_Results.aspx?download=1";
    File file = new File("test.csv");
    URL url;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```